# SQL Joining 2 tables: 1 `ON` vs 2 `ON`

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query like:

```
select gift.id as giftId, gift.title, count(vouchercode.id) as stock, vouchertemplate.unlimited, gift.voucherTemplate, vouchertemplate.id as voucherId,vouchertemplate.title
from gift 
inner join vouchertemplate 
left join vouchercode 
on gift.voucherTemplate = vouchertemplate.id 
on vouchertemplate.id = vouchercode.template 
and vouchercode.given = 0 
where gift.id in (13,14,15,16)
```

I find that this does not give me the correct result. It appears `on gift.voucherTemplate = vouchertemplate.id` does not work as expected. I need it before the left join. So I cannot just put all the join conditions together? I specified the table names and columns to join, so I wonder why the difference?

The below query gives me the correct result.

```
select gift.id as giftId, gift.title, count(vouchercode.id) as stock, vouchertemplate.unlimited, gift.voucherTemplate, vouchertemplate.id as voucherId,vouchertemplate.title
from gift 
inner join vouchertemplate 
on gift.voucherTemplate = vouchertemplate.id  <<< DIFF HERE
left join vouchercode 
on vouchertemplate.id = vouchercode.template 
and vouchercode.given = 0 
where gift.id in (13,14,15,16)
```

Comment: I'm surprised the first one works at all.

Comment: Each `JOIN` clause should have its own `ON` clause that indicates the conditions for joining that table.

Comment: And in top of that, ALWAYS use parenthesis to separate join conditions `bla inner join ble on (a=b and c=d ) left join x ON (d=e and f=g)....`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Why? There's no reason to add parentheses in the join conditions unless you use a complex expression that you need to control the evaluation of. Otherwise it's just visual clutter. In my opinion.

Comment: Instead of relying on MySQLs odd treatment of the `group by` clause I would recommend you to use the standard way of including all non-aggregated columns used in the select in the group by clause.

Comment: @jpw you are right, there's no need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt work that way. You need to have condition for each join. you need to specify on which column (or conidtion) your two tables should be joined.